What are stable C++ frameworks or API handling HTTP and REST, and compatible with OpenApi?
I have to create a set of C++ Linux applications

some being REST servers
some being REST clients

and I am at the stage of selecting good candidates frameworks for that.
I will use C++ 20, or at least 17 for implementation.
When I watch the OpenApi Generator list, server section page, it complies with:

cpp-pistache-server
"Pistache hasn't yet hit the 1.0 release. This means that the project is unstable but not unusable"

cpp-qt-qhttpengine-server
Qt centered I think

cpp-restbed-server
restbed looks abandonned


There others API that looks active, like Boost
but they have no C++ generator from a yaml 3.x OpenApi spec.
Therefore, I'm wondering:
If I am willing to create some C++ applications, some being REST servers, some being REST clients, but all relying on yaml OpenApi specifications,
what would you recommend me to start with?
